# Liberty Profile: binding JNDI values programmatically

Tags: java, jndi, websphere-liberty

I have read that, since Java EE 6, it is possible to programmatically bind values into the java:app:env, java:comp:env and java:global:env. However, when I attempt it, I get a javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException.

I'm doing this from a startup bean, using Liberty 8.5.5.6. Is the problem Liberty, the way I'm coding, or the premise that you can programmatically bind into these namespaces?

(Simplified) code:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class ConfigStartup {        
    @PostConstruct
    void initialize(){
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            ic.bind("java:app:env/LOGGING_LEVEL", "ALL");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Liberty profile does not support write operations to the `java:` namespace.  The EE 7 platform specification never mentions write operations for the `java:` namespace (but often discusses applications declaring resources that the application server should allow applications to read), and the EE compliance test suite apparently does not require write operations, so I think it's quite reasonable for an implementation to disallow them.

If this capability is important to you, you could open a [WebSphere RFE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181), but I would recommend finding an alternative solution.  For example, you're already using a singleton session bean, so you could just store the data in a member variable and have consuming code look up the singleton session bean's `java:global` JNDI name and call a getter method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That answers my question.

Comment: @MichaelWalsh You should click the checkmark to the left of the answer.  It will give me additional reputation, and it will improve your acceptance rate so that others are more likely to answer your questions in the future.